how to do template iteration in lwc
how can i pass iterate values into child component attribute as array in lwc.
import { LightningElement,wire,track } from 'lwc';
export default class SampleLwc extends LightningElement {
     data =[{"prob":"0","dealvalue":50000},{"prob":"10","dealvalue":90000},{"prob":"30","dealvalue":200000},{"prob":"50","dealvalue":1083000,"revenue":"46332.99999999999999999999999999997"},{"prob":"90","dealvalue":260000,"revenue":"260000.0000000000000000000000000001"},{"prob":"100","dealvalue":745000,"revenue":"695000.0000000000000000000000000005"}]
}
}



ex: <c-data label='10%' detail='[dealvalue, revenue]' backgroundcolor='rgba(50, 150, 237, 1)' stack="1"></c-data>


Put it in a getter or variable and pass that array inside the param of the child. You cannot create variables inside the html template.
